# Does the Oxford Comma increase readability?

Tags: readability, grammar

There are many puns online where not having the Oxford comma ([Serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)) can be interpreted as something other than intended, such as the infamous Sky News notification:

[image]

It’s hilarious, I know, but on a more serious note, does the optional serial comma have any effect on readability? Being a Swede, we don’t have that optional rule at all and your Swedish teacher would make you aware of the error and make you correct it. However, when I first found out about it, I thought it increases the readability and leaves out alternative interpretations.

I often find myself stuck with terrible lists, such as a global navigation. You may have Home, Products, Solutions, Services and Support and About Us. Now, do I mean

<kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Products</kbd><kbd>Solutions</kbd><kbd>Services and Support</kbd><kbd>About Us</kbd>

or

<kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Products</kbd><kbd>Solutions</kbd><kbd>Services and Support and About Us</kbd>

It’s obvious to us what I mean since About Us is a top navigation item of its own, but how about nonprofessionals who are not familiar with the standard patterns of a global navigation? Could they misinterpret what I really mean leaving the optional serial comma out of the question? **Does the Oxford Comma increase readability?**

Comment: I don't consider the "Oxford Comma" as optional (certainly it wasn't optional back when I was at school). Is it an American thing to drop this comma?

Comment: @Franchesca From Wikipedia "Opinions among writers and editors differ on whether to use the serial comma. In American English, a majority of style guides mandate use of the serial comma..."

Comment: http://youtu.be/8Gv0H-vPoDc?t=1m45s :-)

Comment: No, serial commas neither increase nor decrease readability by any significant amount. If they significantly increased readability, everyone would use them; if they significantly decreased readability, they'd fall out of use.

Comment: @David: I wonder what proportion of questions on the site could reasonably be answered, "if it made much difference, you wouldn't even be considering two different ways to do it, everyone would already be doing the one that was significantly better. Just pick either of them and get on with your life." ;-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208922

Comment: @SteveJessop - it's not that simple.  There are cases where use of either is objectively wrong.  Consider :  ***To my parents, Jane Doe and Zeus*** versus ***To my parents, Jane Doe, and Zeus*** - here the Oxford comma has eliminated ambiguity.  Alternatively, ***To my mother, Jane Doe, and Zeus*** is ambiguious and *removing* the Oxford Comma clears up the ambiguity :  ***To my mother, Jane Doe and Zeus.***  Most cases can be rephrased in other ways, of course, so sticking to one form or the other means being aware that it imposes some restrictions on the phrasing you use.

Comment: @Franchesca the AP Stylebook has excluded the serial comma, which is a point of contention.  Any news organization that adheres to the AP Stylebook will not use it, as seemingly evidenced by the screenshot in the OP.  If you're interested in more on this subject: http://www.thewire.com/national/2013/05/new-ap-stylebook-oxford-comma-debate/65705/

Comment: Or this, because humor: http://www.theonion.com/articles/4-copy-editors-killed-in-ongoing-ap-style-chicago,30806/

Comment: There are many puns online, but very few (if any) real word examples. If somebody has to rely exclusively on contrived examples to make her/his point that suggests the point is irrevelant.

Comment: @SteveJessop None could, because if that were true, this site wouldn't need to exist. This site is full of people with two different ways to do things, and A/B testing shows that one or the other is superior.

Comment: @CharlesWesley According to your link, the AP style guide actually says to use the comma when needed for clarity. They are only absolute about simple lists, which usually contain nouns and maybe a couple adjectives.

Comment: @BennySkogberg Your second sentence division doesn't work. The list has to separate on the word "and." The other way you could divide that sentence is `Home` `Products` `Solutions` `Services` `and Support and About Us`. I believe this is David's point in the comments below.

Comment: @Franchesca I am an American, and I graduated from a private school 3 years ago. We were taught that it was an error to leave out the serial comma.

Comment: Yes. If nothing else, it prevents the reader from getting distracted thinking "what an idiot the author must be..." while reading. :-)

Comment: @J... That just depends on the sentence. It has a different meaning with/without which is an argument *for* using it - not against!

Comment: @EikePierstorff These "online puns" may be online, but any I've seen are "real world" - just take Sky News from OP?!

Comment: Shouldn't this be on English rather than UX?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: the discussion as to what's "correct" or "incorrect" probably isn't a UX issue, although that's not to say English would *necessarily* want it :-) I'd have thought that copy readability is a UX issue, though.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I was going to comment the same thing that this should be on English.SE

Comment: @OllieFord - In the comment by J..., we have an example where it is better **not to put the last comma**.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco No my point is that the meaning is different **with vs. without** the comma, so it's not a choice or 'better to'.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the top-voted answer is only partially correct... **The Oxford comma can resolve ambiguity OR create ambiguity, depending on context.** This is the reason that grammar experts and style guides disagree on the use of the Oxford comma - sometimes the Oxford comma helps, sometimes it actually hurts readability. Consider the following examples...

"I gave gifts to my parents, Jim and Beth." In this example, the lack of the Oxford comma creates a serious problem! Is "Jim and Beth" an appositive describing my parents, in which case I've given gifts to only two people? Or is this a list of three independent items? There's no way to know. The Oxford comma clears it up, though... "I gave gifts to my parents, Jim, and Beth." Now all is clear! It's a list of three independent items!

**Unfortunately, this can just as easily go the other way!** Consider the following... "I gave gifts to my father, Jim, and Beth." In this case, the presence of the Oxford comma creates serious ambiguity. Is "Jim" an appositive describing my father, in which case I've given gifts to two people? Or is this a list of three different people, and Jim is not my father? With the Oxford comma there, we can't figure it out. But take away the Oxford comma, and it becomes very clear. "I gave gifts to my father, Jim and Beth." Ah! Now we know that three people were involved!

**The Oxford comma does not universally increase or decrease readability.** In some cases it helps, in others it hurts. The best practice is to consult the style guide for whatever you are writing for, follow its rules with respect to the Oxford comma consistently, and **avoid crafting sentences where the Oxford comma or the lack thereof introduces a problem.**

Comment: Why would you structure the sentence to add classifiers to part of a list but not other parts? If you only mean two people when you say "my father, Jim, and Beth", then it should be phrased as "my father, Jim, and my mother, Beth", "my father and mother", or "Jim and Beth". Or in the case that Beth is someone with no possible classifier: "my father and Beth".

Comment: For "I gave gifts to my father, Jim, and Beth", I always reduce the ambiguity by repeating the preposition: "I gave gifts to my father, to Jim, and to Beth" vs "I gave gifts to my father, Jim, and to Beth".

Comment: I would have gone "to my parents and to Jim and Beth". But I guess this isn't english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I absolutely agree with all the above... hence my advice to avoid crafting sentences where the Oxford comma introduces ambiguity. Ultimately, all the rules of language and grammar are arbitrary. The task of a writer is to figure out how to use those arbitrary rules to communicate clearly and effectively.

Comment: Your argument is soft. How many sentences does it help, and how many does it hurt?

Comment: If you can invent a way to calculate that, be my guest...

Answer (score 49):

**Yes. The Oxford Comma increases readability.**

When items are logically separate, putting a delimiter between them makes their separation visually obvious. Without the delimiter, the separation can still be determined, but it is not obvious.

The Oxford comma *removes the requirement that the reader figure out whether item n and item n-1 are logically separate.*

EDIT:

I agree with [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63422/does-the-oxford-comma-increase-readability/63529#63529).

I want to clarify that I gave my original answer in the context of *a list of items which are definitely separate*, such as in the example in the original question. In such a case, I maintain that the Oxford comma does indeed increase readability.

However, many users have very helpfully pointed out that it's possible to construct a list wherein the Oxford comma may not help (and may even hinder) readability. Many of these are cases where the distinction is made by inflection when spoken, but that's of no use in text.

Here's my addendum:

**If you find yourself in a situation where the addition or removal of the Oxford comma does not *unambiguously* improve readability, restructure the whole sentence.**

Comment: The serial comma doesn't do that at all. If "bacon, egg(,) and sausage" were supposed to be a list of two items, there would be an "and" after "bacon". And if the list does have two items, "bacon" and "egg and sausage", it would be written ambiguously as "bacon and egg and sausage" whether the writer used the serial comma or not, since lists of two items don't attract a comma in either convention.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are correct in what yo usay, but I don't see what that has to do with this answer. The answer says that the comma visually separates the items. Your comment involves parsing the sentence. The answer is wrong, but not for the reasons you give, but because it is not always true, as given in an example in the question comments.

Comment: @trlkly The answer is wrong because it claims that the serial comma disambiguates. It doesn't, as my example shows.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know people that would disagree - my parents, Jill and John. I know people that would disagree - my parents, Jill, and John.

Comment: @OllieFord Jill, John(,) and your parents actually agree. Your siblings -- Bob and Sue -- agree too. Fred and Jill, your cousins, are also happy. If you're relying on commas to resolve ambiguity, you should probably rephrase the sentence, anyway.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You're missing the point. Without the 'Oxford Comma', it's not incorrect, it's a different sentence - John, Jill are people who, along with my parent, disagree. I'm not sure if you're seriously suggesting an invented double-dash construct instead.

Comment: @OllieFord If you write "I know people who disagree: my parents, Jill and Bob", I can't tell if you use Oxford commas and you mean "My parents are called Jill and Bob; they agree" or you don't use Oxford commas and you mean "Jill, Bob and my parents disagree." Conversely, if you wrote "My brother, Jim, and Fred", I can't tell if you're using Oxford commas and you mean "Jim, who is my brother, and Fred" or you don't use Oxford commas and you mean "My brother and Jim and Fred." Oxford commas can both resolve and create ambiguity and cannot be parsed unless you know whether the writer uses them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I would leave off the comma *before* Jim if he was my brother.  I'm not sure how I would interpet "My brother, Jim and Fred".  If it had been "My brothers, Jim and Fred" I would think it was talking about my two brothers, while "My brothers, Jim, and Fred" would be Jim, Fred, and my brothers.  If I wanted "Jim" to be a parenthetical identification of "my brother", I would use parentheses rather than commas to delineate it "My brother (Jim) and Fred" or "Joe, my brother (Jim), and Fred".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I completely agree with your observation, and my own conclusion from your observation is that "If Oxford comma didn't have any other alternatives, it would not have caused any confusion, and so everything would be perfect and not ambiguity would present (and so, no discussion on Oxford comma being 'better'). However, since there are alternatives, there are still ambiguities in using Oxford comma. So I wish everybody uses Oxford comma and the world would be a better place, but unfortunately I don't believe it's possible."

Answer (score 15):

I think the key is in *how it sounds* when read aloud.

When people read a sentence they normally "hear" it as speech with their internal voice (theories on this originally based on [Lev Vygotsky's work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Vygotsky#Thought_and_Language), and there are even indications that this [inner speech has an accent](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0025782)).

A comma translates to a pause in speech, so I think readability will be improved if the pauses are in the correct place.

For example, which would sound better to you when reciting a list of items?

- I had sausages *< pause >* bacon *< pause >* and eggs for breakfast.
- I had sausages *< pause >* bacon and eggs for breakfast.

Comment: It's actually kind of hard to tell, but the way it sounds to me, when I try to speak you example sentence naturally, is that the gaps between "sausages" and "bacon" and between "bacon" and "eggs" are of fairly similar length, but the unstressed "and" falls *into* the second gap, partially filling it. (If "bacon and eggs" were a single phrase, like "services and support" in the example above, I'd read it all run together, as in "bacon-n'-eggs". Alas, that looks silly in writing.)

Comment: Commas *do not* translate as pauses in speech. They indicate grammatical structure, not rhythm.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Can you give me an example of a sentence (in English) with a comma / commas where there is no slight pause, break, or change to the rhythm?

Comment: @Franchesca It's perfectly possible and natural to read the sentence you just wrote without pausing each time you come to a comma.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think you must be altering the rhythm without noticing. While commas don't exactly correspond to pauses, they are used to make the same groupings that would be made in speech. If the comma was not in any way apparent in speech, it would be unnecessary, since writing transcribes speech.

Comment: @trlkly If writing transcribes speech, why are computer-generated voices so bad?

Comment: @Franchesca yes, commas often aren't accompanied by even the slightest pause. Speech recognition quantifies the pauses, and the [nonexistant] gaps between syllables in a single word often is the same as the [nonexistant] gaps between words, at commas, and between sentences. *Sometimes*, people do pause for various reasons and emphasis; but in common speech they pause much less often than they believe - you often "hear" pauses and sounds that actually aren't there if you listen at the individual fragments separated out; your mind makes them up based on context.

Comment: If I recite a list of items like that, it doesn't matter which way I do it, I'm going to sound like Borat.

Comment: @Franchesca an example from the very first comment here, if you'd record fragment "... speak you example sentence naturally, is that..." a bunch of times from different speakers speaking fast, I'd guess that in at least half of them the "ly" before comma would merge to the 'is' after the comma as a single sound 'i', a single syllable without any gap at all - something like '...allys that'. People could believe that there's a pause if they'd hear the whole thing (and understand the language), but the recording, the cut-out fragment or people who don't know english wouldn't hear any pause there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: In cases where the rhythm in which something is spoken would very the meaning, punctuation to establish the rhythm may be important even if it would otherwise not be grammatically meaningful.  To borrow an example from Animaniacs, consider "playing catch with your grandfather" versus "playing catch--with--your grandfather" [tossing him around].  Is there any "grammatically correct" way of punctuating the second sentence to distinguish it from the first?

Comment: @supercat I'd probably go for "playing catch with your grandfather" versys "playing catch -- with your grandfather!" But, really, the situation of tossing your grandfather around like a ball is so unusual that you shouldn't expect to make people parse it that way by punctuation alone.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: When Tom Bodett did the voice over for the "Good Idea/Bad Idea" sketch, he put a major pause both before and after "with"; I'm not sure people who hadn't heard the joke would understand it without the accompanying animation, I would suggest that the pauses are not grammatical but are semantically meaningful.  While there are some things which are unambiguous when written but ambiguous when spoken, I would posit that in general the English language has evolved around the notion that writing represents speech, rather than vice versa.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: This is perhaps best illustrated by the usage of "a" or "an" depending upon whether the following word would be *spoken* with an initial vowel sound.  Because English wasn't "designed" as a language, but rather evolved, it's not possible to prescribe "rules" in the same way as one could for Java or C++.

Comment: @DavidRicherby and Franchesca, spoken commas include changes of pitch, not just pauses.  The point is that they do indicate a break of some sort that can't otherwise be written in text.

Comment: The problem with equating commas with pauses is that it's then easy to do the opposite and stick unnecessary commas in a sentence where the voice would pause. And, as @DavidRicherby points out, commas are about sentence structure, not pauses in speech.

Comment: @KenMohnkern I find it absurd that people are freaking out about how commas don't "mean" a pause. What is sentence structure for if it isn't about speech? Why do long sentences sound nicer when broken up with commas, or restructured with full stops? It's because people need to to stop for breath while speaking. Even the internal monologue voice in your head will somewhat stumble over a needlessly long sentence that goes on and on without the kind of pause for breath that a comma might have reasonably allowed you to take had it been present.

Comment: Courtesy of **Modern Family**:
`Only I can kiss my wife, take her to bed, and make her laugh`
~ vs ~
`Only I can kiss my wife, take her to bed and make her laugh`

Answer (score 8):

In the olden days, the written word existed principally to allow reading out loud.  The comma indicated that the reader should leave a very short pause before going on to the next word.  That pause is almost imperceptible, but it affects the way the hearer understands what has been said.  The Oxford comma is no exception.

Without that pause the list is subject to misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

If I look specifically at your example of that list, I'd avoid using that type of serialization entirely, if at all possible. I'd use a simple unordered list and put those below each other in a text.

If you need to use inline serialization, you should try write your sentence to avoid the ambiguity entirely, or at least the serial comma. In this case, I'd use an ampersand (<kbd>&</kbd>) instead of the word <kbd>and</kbd> when talking about services and solutions in a text.

Comment: This is my favourite answer. And a list can be formatted inline.

Answer (score 2):

An ampersand rather than a comma would help solve this and work in menus and lists where commas wouldn't.

Ampersands are used as replacement for "and" with company names, common abreviations etc that are intended to be read as one phrase. So "Services & Support" is more clearly a single option than "services and support".

Of course if you're relying on this level of grammar-finery to make your navigation clear you probably have other problems....

Comment: In the OP's example there is more than an ampersand. There is a full "and". Yet it still reads as if Obama and Castro are getting married, because there is no comma before the "and." A comma should have been included before this particular "and", because there would have been a pause in speech which would have indicated that same-sex marriage was a completely different point from the Obama-Castro handshake.

Comment: The ampersand trick is neat. With the ampersand, the writing gets clarified but there is an ambiguity in speech.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly it would in that case.

Funny, I've never heard about the Oxford Comma, and it would look to me very awkward. In most languages placing the comma before 'and' is an error. But even if it would look awkward, it would make that given example readable.

It took me a plenty of time to understand what that post is about. While date set for same-sex marriages and Obama handshakes sounds awkward, and I've had no idea what is meant by that, I need to read your comment to see that those are 2 separate news.

However, the real problem there is that that sentence is very poorly written. The enumeration with commans and 'ands', no matter if you use the Oxford Commas or not, should be used only for short items, and not for the whole sentences.

> Just use normal commas, Oxford Commas, the words 'and'[,] and ampersands, as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Oxford comma improves readability, but it's no panacea for careless or odd composition. Like any other great power, it can be used irresponsibly.

Some of these examples here are red-herrings, precisely because there are several good ways to improve understanding, regardless of the commas. There are problems you shouldn't try to solve with the Oxford comma. For instance, there's no confusion in "I gave gifts to my father, Jim and *to* Beth." Or, we're totally clear with "I gave gifts to Beth and my father, Jim." Why try to cram those sentences into a series of commas? Or again, why not use classifiers for everyone? Or, who cares what your father's first name is?

It's asinine to look for the Oxford Comma to solve all problems. But when used in a standard list of independent items, it does indeed improve readability. Just don't throw it around willy-nilly, without considering potentially better options, and then blame the poor Oxford comma.

(BTW, here's [some gratuitous humor](http://matthewhance.com/?page_id=150) involving the Oxford comma, strippers, and Stalin. It's actually a pretty good example of a use-case where it clearly improves readability.)

Comment: Your sentence "I gave gifts to my father, Jim and to Beth." is awkward. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Lots of formal syntax that is technically grammatical has come to sound awkward or stilted. I believe that sentence fits the bill. Yet, I still find it difficult to misunderstand. Given that we're talking about ambiguity, what alternate interpretation do you see?

Comment: My interpretation is that the sentence misses symmetry. It looks that an apposition for "my father" starts but never ends. The sentence is not correct. It means nothing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consult your company's style guide. In my own writing I always use it because I think it improves clarity. In my business writing I never use it because the companies I've worked for had style guides in place that specified not to use it.

Don't have a style guide? Not gonna make one? Then just pick a style and be consistent. (And have as many coworkers be consistent as possible.)

In your example, you could improve clarity without the serial comma by quoting each item: You may have "Home," "Products," "Solutions," "Services and Support" and "About Us." (Yes, the commas and periods go inside the quotes.)

Comment: Why do the commas and periods go inside the quotes? They're not part of the thing you're trying to quote.

Comment: It's a typographic standard, developed over the centuries. I don't have a logical reason for it; I suspect we do it because commas and periods look better tucked inside the quotes. (Look at professionally typeset works - NYT, books, magazines - and you'll see it all the time.)

Comment: It's a typographic standard *in some places*. The typographic standards I'm familiar with put the punctuation in or out of the quotes, depending on whether it's part of the quote. So, for example, "He asked, 'Do you like cheese?'" versus "Did she say, 'I hate cheese'?"

Comment: Note, the "standard" re: quotes is arguably incorrect in a number of contexts (like programming) where a piece of punctuation can make something totally wrong.  I personally consider it incorrect everywhere, and refuse to use it, unless the punctuation is part of the quote.

Comment: I think the remark on punctuation is just mistaken. In the sentence ("Yes," she said, "I do.") the punctuation can go inside the quotes, fair enough. In the sentence: (A "selfie", as the youngsters call it, is a photo of yourself) it can't, although you could use italics instead to avoid the issue. When listing labels in quotes there should be nothing in the quotes other than the exact label text. I used parentheses to quote my examples there because I really don't think that nesting different types of quotation marks would improve clarity in this case!

Comment: @SteveJessop The point David is making is that there are some (mostly American) guides that say the comma and period always go inside quotes, while other style guides say they go on the outside if they aren't a part of the original. I was definitely taught in school here in the U.S. that periods and commas always go inside quotation marks. In any English paper, I would definitely write  "A 'selfie,' as the youngsters call it, is a photo of yourself." If I didn't, I my paper would get marked up.

Comment: I *despise* punctuation in quotes. It's disgusting. I believe it originates in the US, but I certainly know people here (UK) that claim it's correct. Ugh.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the US. And again, I'd suggest you conform to the style guide for your company. But in (US) journalism and publishing, commas and periods are placed inside the quote. (Question marks and exclamations are outside when that makes logical sense, @David Richerby.) If I were setting a programming text I'd use something other than quotes (italics or bold, maybe) to specify code.

Comment: @trlkly mentions "some guides." The AP and Chicago guides are commonly used here in the US. Lots of businesses default to one of those if they don't have their own guide. It doesn't look like I can nicely paste URLs into a comment, so I'll leave it up to the interested parties to google them.

Comment: @OllieFord: Punctuation within quotes is appropriate in cases where punctuation exists in both places, even if the logical punctuation inside would be a period, but it's replaced by a comma because that's what's needed outside.  "I see you," she said.  Otherwise, I consider the "punctuation inside quotes always" as being one of many which are designed to make different people's writing be indistinguishable.  When many people write works under a common pen name, it's perfectly reasonable for the owner of that pen name to dictate a particular writing style, but that shouldn't be taken to...

Comment: ...imply that anyone who isn't writing under that pen name should use that style.  Unfortunately, things like the "AP style guide" are often regarded as an indication of how everyone should write, rather than as an indication of how the pseudonymous author "Associated Press" writes.  Likewise, early Linotype equipment may have been unable to accommodate a wider space after sentence-ending punctuation than in other contexts, and some publishers may have decided they didn't want to deal with the wide-space-vs-narrow-space distinction and homogenized everything, but...

Comment: ...that doesn't meant that having more space after a sentence vs after an abbreviation is "wrong".  Examination of pre-Linotype printing would suggest that having more space after sentence-ending periods as expected, though many people seem to think the concept was invented by people using typewriters and should be abandoned when using proportional type.

Comment: @KenMohnkern If you click the "help" link next to the comment box, it shows how to put nice links in comments

Comment: Your commas and period inside the quotes are absurd. As absurd as the big U in "About Us".

Answer (score 0):

Foremost, I think we need to recognize what an Oxford comma is. It's only used in the case of lists of at least three items. All of these use-cases about parents' names are absurd and wrong, regardless of your grammatical background. Your parents, Bob and Alice, never have commas after the first name. If it's a really big deal, you could replace parenthetical commas with actual parentheses or reorganize the sentence. Bob and Alice, my parents, won't get confused if you avoid the conjunction.

As far as readability goes, it's fuzzy. This discussion has involved numerous complicated sentence structures where it's complicated with or without the comma. Using it will not improve readability nearly as much as restructuring the sentence would. As we've found numerous examples to demonstrate, using the comma in a parenthetical phrase already enclosed in commas is going to be confusing. However, not using it will probably also be confusing because of so many commas nearby anyway.

Regarding the original example of headlines, an Oxford comma reduces ambiguity and it's probably a good idea to use it in such a case where list items might include conjunctions. However, it's not better in all cases and sentence structure will have a bigger impact if it's not a straight-forward list.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Michael.  At the moment, the first two paragraphs of your post appear to be a commentary on other answers rather than an answer.  The third paragraph does address the question, but it reads as only opinion; it would be stronger if can provide some evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Objective evidence strongly suggests that the Oxford comma does not consistently and universally help readability.  By this, I mean that there is a strong cross-Atlantic difference in the use of commas in general and the Oxford comma in particular: modern American editors use them much more often than modern British editors.  (I have no idea what the rest of the English-speaking world does.)  When I started reading British books as a kid -- I mean ones imported from Britain, not ones by a British author typeset here in the US -- I got confused by all the "missing" commas that I expected from American literature.  But when I read literature where *every* possible comma is included in long sentences, I get confused by the "extra" commas.  British readers on the whole, I imagine, get confused if there are more commas than they were used to seeing when they learned to read and generally prefer the versions without Oxford commas the same way I prefer versions with them.

If one style of comma usage were universally superior, style guides in Britain and the US would long ago have come into line as editors became frustrated by years of "hard-to-read" text.